# Uncovering items and changing frame title with beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

The usual behavior of `beamer` when using `\framebreak` is to change the title of the current frame by adding a "local numbering" of the slide within those "broken frames".

I would like to achieve the same result on some frames (this can't be a global behavior change) when using `\uncover`, `\only`, `\alt` and such, but for now, I do it by hand, e.g.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{HELLO \uncover<1->{I}\uncover<2->{I}\uncover<3->{I}}
\uncover<1->{ A \\}
\uncover<2->{ B \\}
\uncover<3->{ C \\}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So my two question are pretty straightforward : do you know how to this properly (for example, I can't go beyond a counter value of 3 in this piece of code)? and what is the `beamer` counter that stores the "local numbering" I was referring to earlier in this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly your message, you're trying to put in the frame title the Roman number of the slide:

```
\newcommand{\slidenumber}[1]{%
  \csname @#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname beamer@slideinframe\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{HELLO \slidenumber{Roman}}
\uncover<1->{ A \\}
\uncover<2->{ B \\}
\uncover<3->{ C \\}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can use also `\slidenumber{arabic}`, `\slidenumber{roman}` or even `\slidenumber{alph}` and `\slidenumber{Alph}`.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about `beamer@slideinframe` !